# Take Node between Two Nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have Xml In the below Format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<htmlString>
<ACTION v="Search"/>
<KEY/>
<ACCOUNTNO v=""/>
<AGREEMENTREF1/>
<AGREEMENTREF2/>
<PAYMENTREF1/>
<PAYMENTREF2/>
<PROGRAM v="SOW03301"/>
<SESSION v="SF3gGV1J4501"/>
<OBJECT v="1"/>
<HTMLFILE v="CGIOTP000023/TEMP:WHTTP"/>
<PIPECOUNTER v="100000386"/>
</htmlString>
```

I need the Part between ACTION  and SESSION as a string.

```
<KEY/>
<ACCOUNTNO v=""/>
<AGREEMENTREF1/>
<AGREEMENTREF2/>
<PAYMENTREF1/>
<PAYMENTREF2/>
<PROGRAM v="SOW03301"/>
```

Can you help on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking questions, make sure you include what you have tried.  As it stands, it sounds like you are using StackOverflow as a code generator.  See the help center for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `XElement.ElementsAfterSelf`:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<htmlString>
<ACTION v=""Search""/>
<KEY/>
<ACCOUNTNO v=""""/>
<AGREEMENTREF1/>
<AGREEMENTREF2/>
<PAYMENTREF1/>
<PAYMENTREF2/>
<PROGRAM v=""SOW03301""/>
<SESSION v=""SF3gGV1J4501""/>
<OBJECT v=""1""/>
<HTMLFILE v=""CGIOTP000023/TEMP:WHTTP""/>
<PIPECOUNTER v=""100000386""/>
</htmlString>";

var xd = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var elements = xd.Root.Element("ACTION")
    .ElementsAfterSelf()
    .TakeWhile(xe => xe.Name.LocalName != "SESSION")
    .Select(xe => xe.ToString());
var sbNew = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, elements);

Console.Write(sbNew);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Prints:

```
<KEY />
<ACCOUNTNO v="" />
<AGREEMENTREF1 />
<AGREEMENTREF2 />
<PAYMENTREF1 />
<PAYMENTREF2 />
<PROGRAM v="SOW03301" />
```